# How to create a heatmap with different color ranges for the sum column?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I've got my pd.dataframe ready.

```
            Communication Services  Consumer Discretionary  Consumer Staples  Energy  Financials  Health Care  Industrials  Materials  Real Estate  Technology  Utilities  Sum
Date                                                                                                                                                                          
2020-09-15  61                      65                      39                3       36          53           68           89         74           43          53         584
2020-09-14  50                      70                      39                7       54          45           67           92         64           28          53         569
2020-09-11  38                      54                      30                0       28          27           46           82         25           18          28         376
2020-09-10  30                      52                      24                0       16          19           30           67         32           12          25         307
2020-09-09  50                      57                      36                0       33          30           52           71         51           30          42         452
2020-09-08  34                      55                      21                0       24          16           24           46         48           12          25         305
2020-09-04  53                      59                      51                3       66          32           47           71         74           35          28         519
2020-09-03  57                      67                      57                0       48          40           49           82         80           52          32         564
2020-09-02  73                      85                      78                3       80          74           94           89         87           94          64         821
2020-09-01  69                      78                      54                3       54          51           79           85         51           77          14         615
2020-08-31  76                      73                      78                7       50          61           75           64         54           70          21         629
2020-08-28  92                      81                      75                30      81          48           86           89         77           76          17         752
2020-08-27  88                      77                      81                11      83          53           82           82         70           64          14         705
2020-08-26  92                      81                      75                11      46          43           79           89         45           69          7          637
2020-08-25  92                      86                      78                23      65          45           82           82         64           64          21         702
2020-08-24  92                      88                      90                38      62          38           90           75         54           61          39         727
2020-08-21  80                      78                      69                11      28          37           71           50         45           49          17         535
2020-08-20  84                      72                      63                11      34          45           78           57         45           57          17         563
2020-08-19  80                      83                      81                34      48          56           84           71         29           60          35         661
2020-08-18  88                      88                      90                53      48          62           91           71         70           64          42         767
2020-08-17  80                      95                      87                80      69          62           94           78         77           63          42         827
2020-08-14  84                      100                     90                80      83          56           94           78         64           57          42         828
2020-08-13  88                      98                      87                69      81          56           95           78         64           66          57         839
2020-08-12  73                      96                      87                96      83          58           98           75         90           63          64         883
2020-08-11  73                      86                      72                84      89          50           95           78         77           53          46         803
2020-08-10  80                      93                      87                88      83          53           93           78         90           64          82         891
2020-08-07  69                      81                      84                65      84          58           91           60         83           71          89         835
2020-08-06  73                      80                      81                73      60          53           84           57         54           78          67         760
2020-08-05  69                      81                      87                73      68          69           89           64         51           78          64         793
2020-08-04  80                      63                      87                73      46          66           64           53         67           81          85         765
2020-08-03  69                      55                      78                50      60          74           68           42         51           81          78         706
2020-07-31  65                      62                      78                42      60          61           64           46         58           74          92         702
2020-07-30  65                      62                      75                34      65          74           71           50         64           61          89         710
2020-07-29  73                      78                      90                88      90          87           79           85         70           64          85         889
2020-07-28  46                      67                      81                38      71          72           78           85         61           47          89         735
2020-07-27  61                      78                      90                61      86          75           76           96         32           74          75         804
2020-07-24  80                      77                      87                73      87          72           83           100        32           56          96         843
2020-07-23  84                      81                      90                73      90          85           91           100        38           73          96         901
2020-07-22  88                      90                      90                84      92          93           94           100        45           90          96         962
2020-07-21  76                      91                      93                96      92          93           93           100        25           85          92         936
2020-07-20  65                      81                      81                34      62          91           84           96         32           87          89         802
2020-07-17  76                      86                      93                38      65          95           91           96         51           77          100        868
2020-07-16  80                      90                      93                50      81          93           89           96         22           70          85         849
2020-07-15  80                      96                      87                53      78          95           91           96         45           76          75         872
2020-07-14  69                      59                      81                23      53          82           73           96         25           60          82         703
2020-07-13  57                      34                      69                0       46          54           56           71         9            43          75         514
2020-07-10  61                      44                      66                0       43          59           39           60         35           66          64         537
2020-07-09  46                      31                      42                0       18          61           36           32         32           61          46         405
2020-07-08  50                      42                      57                3       34          67           50           46         25           61          57         492
2020-07-07  53                      34                      60                0       18          66           43           75         22           50          46         467
2020-07-06  50                      52                      54                7       30          75           64           89         41           76          53         591
```

Now I'd like to plot a heatmap by using matplotlib. The resulting heatmap should look something like this:

[image]

For the inner part (columns besides "sum"), if the value is above 50, then the color should be green, and the color should be darker for the largest values. Same logic for the values below 50.

For the "sum" column, the threshold is 550. How to achieve the gradual change in color?

Comment: google seaborn heatmap. I find it easier to use than matplotlib and its better looking too.

Comment: Do you want to plot heatmap or just [styling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html)?

Comment: i only have the dataframe right now. i want to plot a heatmap and style the graph like the picture above.

Comment: i need to style the "Sum" column and the other columns with different rules. the first threshold of changing color is 50, while the second one is 550.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `sns.diverging_palette(20, 145)` standard has white in the center. Possible hue values for red are `20`, and `145` for green.

`vmin=` will then set the numeric value corresponding to red and `vmax=` for the value corresponding to green. The value in the center will be white.

You need to create 2 separate heatmaps as they have different color ranges. The `ax=` keyword tells on which subplot the heatmap should be created. The colorbars can be left out: the numbers inside the cells already indicate the correspondence.

A newline character in the label names helps to better use the available space.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

# df = pd.read_csv(...)
# df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
column_labels = [col.replace(' ', '\n') for col in df.columns[:-1]]
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 10),
                               gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': [10, 1], 'wspace': 0.02, 'bottom': 0.14})
cmap = sns.diverging_palette(20, 145)
sns.heatmap(df[df.columns[:-1]], cmap=cmap, vmin=0, vmax=100, annot=True, fmt='.0f', annot_kws={'fontsize': 10},
            lw=0.6, xticklabels=column_labels, cbar=False, ax=ax1)
sns.heatmap(df[df.columns[-1:]], cmap=cmap, vmin=0, vmax=1100, annot=True, fmt='.0f', annot_kws={'fontsize': 10},
            lw=0.6, yticklabels=[], cbar=False, ax=ax2)
ax2.set_ylabel('')
ax2.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=90)
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: yes.I added `square=True` in the heatmap, how to adjust the square size to make it bigger? i still wonder if my table contains 100 rows, how to fit them in the image? @JohanC

Comment: Increase the `figsize` will make the plot larger. You could also create one plot with the first half and another one with the second half of the data. Or maybe one plot per month? Setting `square=True` will have as drawback that the cell will be too narrow to contain the text, as well as making it a lot harder for the 'sum' subplot to be close enough to the main subplot.

Comment: is there any other better method to adjust the cell ratio? I'm just trying to make the cells "taller". I see the drawback you mentioned.

Comment: Default, the cell widths and heights are adjusted so that everything fits into the figure. So, you could make the figure narrower and/or higher to get the effect of "taller" cells.

Comment: i think i increased the image height by changing the parameter in `figsize`, but the image still remains the same. Could you please take a look at:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63945678/overlapping-cells-in-seaborn-heatmap

Answer (score 0):

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))
sns.heatmap(data, annot=True, cmap="YlGnBu", linewidths=.5)
```

[image]

Is that what you are looking for.
and also If you want to add range on the values you can use vmin, vmax parameters.

Comment: i think the sum column is missing and I didn't find the GreenWhiteRed option. do you know how to adjust that?

Comment: If you want to include sum also you can do this but in that scenario if you use vmin, vmax it will be not useful for you because sum usually have higher values then single value and most of the heatmap will look faded.